# How to use comma with both ... and ...?

Tags: commas

In the sentence below, is the comma placed correctly? Why?

> "Her performance was highly acclaimed, both for her rich and
>   beautiful voice and for her powerful stand"

Comment: "Both ... stand" is basically a "parenthetical" and would have commas at both ends if there was anything after it.

Answer (score 0):

If you try reading it without the comma, it is hard to know where the sentence is going once you finish reading the word "both". Interestingly, if you take the word "both" out, the sentence doesn't really need the comma. Adding the word provides clarity, but only if it is separated from the the word "acclaimed". By defining that separation, the comma makes clear that "both" is not associated with "acclaimed", but rather with the two prepositional phrases beginning with "for".